# saiku Date Difference error

Tags: mdx, datediff, saiku

I am getting wrong result while calculating date difference between two dates using saiku.

```
/*** Query ***/
With Member Measures.DD as 
   DateDiff('d',CDate('Mar 20, 2014'),CDate('Apr 19, 2014'),3,3)
select {Measures.DD,Measures.DF} on Columns 
from [Cube_AR]

/*** Output ***/
1

/*** Expected Output ***/
30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fuller dates and also I usually use double quotes around my `"D"`.

```
With Member Measures.DD as 
   DateDiff("D",CDate('March 20, 2014'),CDate('April 19, 2014'),3,3)
select {Measures.DD,Measures.DF} on Columns 
from [Cube_AR]
```

3 is a strange day to have as the first day of the week?

Comment: Even I remove the "day of week" part from the above query didn't work

Comment: DateDiff("D",CDate('March 20, 2014'),CDate('April 19, 2014'),3,3)  works in SSAS . I need to find date difference in Mondrian MDX

Comment: What do you mean "fuller dates" ??

Comment: @BerkinAlbertAntonyW when I say "fuller" I mean try using "March" instead od "Mar" or use "April" rather than the shorter version "Apr" ...

Comment: Really I didn't get expected output even I tried with fuller dates. Which version of Saiku, Schema Workbench, Pentaho you are using..

Comment: @BerkinAlbertAntonyW I'm not using Saiku - I just like playing with mdx. Can you test if CDate is functioning correctly? If you change `'March 20, 2014'` to `'March 21, 2014'` does your result still show 1 or does it change to 2?